# Using a Parameter As An IDENTITY starting number

Tags: sql, identity, temp-tables

I am writing a query which creates some test accounts. I am giving my stored procedure an INT which is a starting number - and want it to simply create accounts which have a number 1 more than the one before it since each account number must be different. I have removed almost all the items from the table, but here is what I am trying to use:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempAccount (AccountNumber INT IDENTITY((@StartingAccountNumber), 1)
```

And it is giving me a "incorrect syntax '@StartingAccountNumber'. Expecting '(', or SELECT"

Some searching around the internet has given me a potential solution:

```
DECLARE @Statement VARCHAR(200)
SET @Statement = 'ALTER TABLE BA 
ADD ES INT IDENTITY(' + CAST(@CurrentES AS VARCHAR) + ', 1);'
EXEC (@Statement)
```

However - I was informed this is not an option for this project. Is there any way to inject my paramater in a way similar to my original intent?

Comment: Why is not an option for your project ?

Comment: I was instructed to not use dynamic SQL. More searching around the web makes it appear it may be the only way to get something like this to work it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DBCC CHECKIDENT to do it.  First create the table, then reseed it using this command.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempAccount (AccountNumber INT IDENTITY(1, 1))

Declare @StartingAccountNumber int
SET @StartingAccountNumber = 1000

DBCC CHECKIDENT
(
    #TempAccount, RESEED, @StartingAccountNumber

)
```

You can read about it here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/how-do-i-reseed-a-sql-server-identity-column/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is to generate a monotonic series of numbers, correct?

It is often useful to have a utility table around that contains a large range of continous integer values, something like this:

```
create table dbo.sequence ( id int not null primary key clustered )
go

set nocount on
go
declare @n  int = -1000000 
while ( @n < +1000000 )
begin
  insert dbo.sequence values ( @n )
  set @n = @n+1
end
go
set nocount on
go
```

You only have to do with once. Once you have such a source, things get easy:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempAccount ( AccountNumber int primary key clustered )

declare @starting_account_number int = 123456789
declare @count                   int = 10000

insert #TempAccount ( AccountNumber )
select @starting_account_number + offset.id
from dbo.sequence offset
where offset.id between 0 and @count-1
```